# Lighter Than Air

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My first is in pleasure, but never in sleeping;
>   My next is in smiles, but never in weeping.
>   My third can be found in both lemons and limes;
>   My fourth is in moments, but never in time.
>   My fifth is in children, but not in their cries;
>   My sixth is in girls, but is never in guys.
>   My last is in peaches, and also in pears.
>   My whole, when you find it, is lighter than air!

***What am I?***

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the answer is

> "ammonia"
>  Each line in the riddle, except the last one, represents a letter from this word that follows the rules:
>  "a" is in the word "pleasure", but not in "sleeping"
>  "m" is in the word "smiles", but not in "weeping"
>  "m" is in both in the word "lemons" and in "limes"
>  "o" is in the word "moments", but not in the word "time"
>  "n" is in the word "children", but not in the word "cries"
>  "i" is in the word "girls", but not in the word "guys"
>  "a" is both in the word "peaches" and in the word "pears"
>  The last line in the riddle refers to the fact that ammonia is twice as light as the air.